# Can't pass json response to variable in React using Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using React with Axios. I have a json file and trying to get the data passed to my React App.

$url is the url of the Json file and when I run console log I can see that the json data is getting logged, so think I am fetching the data correctly, but it does not seem to be assigning the data to my variables.

My console log shows like below

```
Array [ {…} ]
​
0: Object { title: "Page Title", body: "<p>Page body</p>", uri: "uri.jpg", … }
​
length: 1
```

This is my code

```
const PageDetails = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState();
  const [morePages, setMorePages] = useState();

  const fetchPageDetails = () => {

    axios({
     url: $url,
     method: 'get'
     })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      setPage(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    
  };

  return (

    <h1>{page[0]?.title}</h1>
    <div>{page[0]?.body}</div>

  );
};
```

However, I get error page is undefined.

How can I pass the json response? Thanks

Comment: Should be `page?.[0].title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get error page is undefined.

No initial value is provided, so the default is `undefined`:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState();
```

You can provide an initial value of an empty array if you like:

```
const [page, setPage] = useState([]);
```

Alternatively, you can modify the optional chaining to support an `undefined` value in `page`:

```
page?.[0]?.title
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you call the fetch function?

It seems you need to use useEffect to call it on initial render.

Also you need to set default state.

```
const PageDetails = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState([]);
  const [morePages, setMorePages] = useState();

  const fetchPageDetails = () => {

    axios({
     url: $url,
     method: 'get'
     })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      setPage(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    
  };

  useEffect(fetchPageDetails, [])

  return (

    <h1>{page[0]?.title}</h1>
    <div>{page[0]?.body}</div>

  );
};
```